# Is there anyway to make PRAW faster for discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, praw

This works and I have no issue with it. my bot is about 1100 lines of code so not that much. I have a standard meme command using PRAW. Is there any way to make its response time faster and not embedding it is not an option. My ms is average.

**code:**

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def meme(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("meme")
    all_subs = []

    top = subreddit.top(limit=50)

    for submission in top:
        all_subs.append(submission)

    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url

    embed = discord.Embed(title = name)

    embed.set_image(url=url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store a meme and then send it later. By sending and then getting a meme, you do not have to wait to get a meme before sending one. Then you prepare for the next one.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def meme(ctx):
    
    if not hasattr(client, 'nextMeme'):
        client.nextMeme = getMeme()

    name, url = client.nextMeme
    embed = discord.Embed(title = name)

    embed.set_image(url=url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    client.nextMeme = getMeme()


def getMeme():
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("meme")   

    top = subreddit.top(limit=50)

    for submission in top:
        all_subs.append(submission)

    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url

    return name, url
```

I changed bot to client, if client does not work for you then replace it with bot.

Comment: One small thing, you can also use `bot.nextMeme` just like `global nextMeme`.

Comment: I updated the same code to use that instead. Thank you!

Comment: It says bot is not defined

Comment: The answer is now updated with your edit; it should work with `client` now.