# How to make my meme command response faster? in discord py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, praw

Yes i have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236351/is-there-anyway-to-make-praw-faster-for-discord-py) but that did not help at all. I want to preload memes or just cache them in one way, or any other thing to decrease the time to wait. I have tried to use asyncpraw but for some reason, `subreddit.top` doesn't work there, so i'll stick to praw. My goal is to decrease the time to wait, because i have to wait more than 10 seconds, and the bot crashes if i spam the meme command. so i need to fix this issue.

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 
import praw
from bot_config.settings import botowner, avatarowner
from discord import Embed

    @commands.command(aliases=["memes", "r/memes", "reddit"])
    async def meme(self, ctx, subred="memes"):
        msg = await ctx.send('Loading ... <a:Loading:845258574434795570>')

        reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='ID',
                             client_secret='SECRET',
                             username="USERNAME",
                             password='PASSWORD',
                             user_agent='AGENT')

        subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subred)
        all_subs = []
        top = subreddit.top(limit=350)

        for submission in top:
            all_subs.append(submission)

        random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

        name = random_sub.title
        url = random_sub.url

        embed = Embed(title=f'__{name}__', colour=discord.Colour.random(), 
                      timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, url=url)

        embed.set_image(url=url)
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Bot by {botowner}', icon_url=avatarowner)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.edit(content=f'<https://reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/>  :white_check_mark:')
        return
```

Comment: You show no effort at doing that preloading/caching at all. Where are you stuck with it?

Comment: Maybe instead of creating a new `praw.Reddit` instance per command why not have one global instance and re-use it? Also instead of using `praw` use [`asyncpraw`](https://pypi.org/project/asyncpraw/)

Comment: with asyncpraw it tells me "Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'top'" and with normal praw everything works fine. i dont know where the issue is, i read that both of them are the same when coding. i dont have preloading progress, because i dont know how to it. i tried the linked post, but that didn't work fine.

Comment: They are not the same. `asyncpraw` is the asynchronous version of `praw`, you gotta use the `await` keyword every now and then. What's the purpose of creating the `praw.Reddit` instance every time you run the command?

Comment: i try it again with asyncpraw but i still get the same error, that coroutine object has no top attribute. i think i just dont know how to use it. with praw.Reddit i watched a tutorial, but i think i made it global by putting it at the top of the code. if this is the method to make something global, i am new at discord py and dont have much experience with it

Answer (score 0):

Basically this uses the same idea that the post you referenced uses but I adapted it from your code.

```
all_subs = []
oldSubred = "memes"
@commands.command(aliases=["memes", "r/memes", "reddit"])
async def meme(self, ctx, subred="memes"):
    global oldSubred
    if oldSubred != subred: # This checks if the subreddit from the previous time you used this command is the same as this time, if it's not, it picks brand new submissions, if it is, then the bot will use the submissions it got from the last time it ran the command, shortening the time needed to get a submission to send by a LOT
        all_subs.clear() # Clears all_subs if the desired subreddit is different from the posts inside all_subs

    msg = await ctx.send('Loading ... <a:Loading:845258574434795570>')

# You really shouldn't be logging into praw EVERY time you want to run this command, put this above the @commands.command
 #   reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='ID',
 #                           client_secret='SECRET',
 #                           username="USERNAME",
 #                           password='PASSWORD',
 #                           user_agent='AGENT')

    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subred)

    if all_subs == []: # Only gathers posts if all_subs is empty
        top = subreddit.top(limit=350)
        for submission in top:
            all_subs.append(submission)

    random_sub = all_subs[0] # Not really random anymore, just goes through the list
    all_subs.pop() # Gets rid of the 0 index variable from all_subs that we just used above

    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url

    embed = Embed(title=f'__{name}__', colour=discord.Colour.random(), 
                    timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, url=url)

    embed.set_image(url=url)
    embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Bot by {botowner}', icon_url=avatarowner)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.edit(content=f'<https://reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/>  :white_check_mark:')
```

I'm no professional so please point out any flaws if you see them.